# Power BI Growth Rate Change %

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working on a data visualization on STOCK MARKET TRADES and I need to calculate the Average Growth Rate of the Stock daily.

But the catch is, that they don't always deal everyday. They only do Monday-Friday. I can't seem to find a workaround for this.

Logic is simple but I'm having trouble with it in Power BI

Data is like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ7wO.jpg

I've tried using the function `EARLIER()` but it doesn't work for me.

```
today = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('sample'[price]))

yesterday = CALCULATE(
  [today], 
  DATEADD('sample'[DATE],-1,DAY),
  ALL('sample'[DATE].[Day]),
  ALL(' sample'[Day Name])
)
```

Comment: Please consider commenting/marking as solved on proposed solutions if they are successful or not or appreciating someone's work with an upvote. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `EARLIER` function this way:

```
Yesterday = 
CALCULATE(
          MAX('sample'[Price]),
          FILTER(
                'sample',
                'sample'[DATE]<EARLIER('sample'[DATE])
                )
         )
```